# How do I vertically align two nav bar items, then an image and then again two nav bar items in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I want to make the home screen of my website like this:

[image]

And I have the following code in HTML:

```
<body>
 <li class="aboutme"><a href="#">Over Mij</a></li>
 <li class="resume"><a href="#">Resumé</a></li>
 <img class="home_cartoon" src="cartoon.png">
 <li class="portfolio"><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
 <li class="contact"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</body>
```

I don't know what I have to do with my CSS to get it like the image I've added, can someone help me?

Comment: validate your code in https://validator.w3.org/.

Comment: incorrect markup

Comment: are you using bootstrap?

Comment: @rajibkarmaker No I don't, should I?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you have to use an `ul` container around `li` elements and also put the image into an `li` to get valid HTML. Make all `li`s inline-blocks and apply `vertical-align: middle;` to them:

```css
li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <ul>
    <li class="aboutme"><a href="#">Over Mij</a></li>
    <li class="resume"><a href="#">Resumé</a></li>
    <li><img class="home_cartoon" src="https://placehold.it/120x200"></li>
    <li class="portfolio"><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li class="contact"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
  
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
 
    text-align: center;
    padding: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
    background-color: #111111;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<ul>
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://placeholder.com"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"></a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

just insert float:left in li elements and it will do the rest of work for u.
please view this in full screen as this example is not responsive to screen sizes

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with CSS Grid Layout:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
  list-style-position: inside;
}

body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 5px;
  height: 100px;
  height: 300px;
  justify-items: center;
}

li, img {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

li {
  align-self: center;
}

img {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
   <li class="aboutme"><a href="#">Over Mij</a></li>
   <li class="resume"><a href="#">Resumé</a></li>
   <img class="home_cartoon" src="https://torange.biz/photofx/5/8/image-profile-picture-beautiful-exotic-flower-5532.jpg">
   <li class="portfolio"><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
   <li class="contact"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</body>
```

Answer (score -2):

Use flexbox , something like :

```
body{
display: flex;
align-items: center;
}
```

be sure of the size of the container , in this case the body